# Dynamic Component Creation using "force:inputField"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

@SkipSauls wrote an amazing article on how to use FieldSets in Lightning Components. Thank you!

[Link here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56047/how-to-use-fieldsets-with-lightning)

But it seems like, using this approach, we can only use OOTB aura components (ui:textbox, ui:button) . But these components are not compatible with Lightning Design System.

Hence i started creating generic custom components (c:customComponent) and used it when creating dynamic components using $A.createComponent(....).

But creating generic components (with LDS Support) which supports all different types of metadata seems to consume enormous time.

Is there a better way to approach it?

I am trying to see if there is a better way such as usage of "force:inputfield" inside $A.createComponent(...) so that Salesforce Platform can determine and render components using respective metadata automatically.

Have anyone tried this approach ? It doesn't seem to work for me.

**Here is my first Try (This works, but too painful and time consuming to build all generic components).**

**PageLayoutManager.cmp**

```
<aura:component access="GLOBAL" controller="PageLayoutManagerApexController"
                implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">

    <!-- Public Page Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="fieldSetName" type="String" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="lazyLoad" type="Boolean" default="true" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="totalColumns" type="Integer" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="dataTransportMode" type="String" access="global" 
                                                           description="Enables to pass-in values by data-wrapper [OR] 
                                                                        by providing fieldSet Name. 
                                                                        Accepted Values: (FieldSet [OR] DataWrapper)" />

    <!-- Private Page Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="fieldWrapperList" type="object" access="private" />

    <!-- Context Aware Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="a0Dg000000636rzEAA" />
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" default="KYCOnboard__c"/>

    <!-- Page Handlers -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}" />

    <!-- Future Functionality -->
    <aura:attribute name="dataWrapper" type="Object" />

    <!-- Dynamic UI Markup -->
    <div class="slds">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.body}" var="bodyElement">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    {!bodyElement}
                </div>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

**PageLayoutManagerController.js**

```
({
    onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("PageLayoutManager -- onInit() -- ENTRY");
        helper.getFieldSetMetadata(component, helper);
        console.log("PageLayoutManager -- onInit() -- EXIT");
    }
})
```

**PageLayoutManagerHelper.js**

```
({
    getFieldSetMetadata : function(component, helper) {
        console.log("PageLayoutManager -- helper.getFieldSetMetadata() -- ENTRY");

        var SObjectName = component.get("v.sObjectName");
        var FieldSetName = component.get("v.fieldSetName");
        var RecordId = component.get("v.recordId");

        //Getting Apex Method Instance        
        var action = component.get("c.getApexFieldSetMetadata");

        if(SObjectName && FieldSetName){
            action.setParams({
                sObjectName : SObjectName,
                fieldSetName : FieldSetName,
                recordId : RecordId
            });

            $A.enqueueAction(action);
            console.log('getFieldSetMetadata() - Request Initalized to Apex Controller ');

            var self = this;

            //Handle Response back from Apex Controller.
            action.setCallback(self, function(response){
                var callbackState = response.getState();
                var fieldWrapperList = response.getReturnValue();

                if(callbackState === "SUCCESS"){
                    console.log('getFieldSetMetadata() - Response...');
                    console.table(response.getReturnValue());
                    component.set("v.fieldWrapperList", fieldWrapperList);
                    helper.constructDynamicComponents(component, helper, fieldWrapperList);
                }else if(callbackState === "ERROR"){
                    console.log('Something went wrong!');
                }
            });
        }
        console.log("PageLayoutManager -- helper.getFieldSetMetadata() -- EXIT");
    },

    constructDynamicComponents : function(component, helper, fieldWrapperList){
        console.log("PageLayoutManager -- helper.constructDynamicComponents() -- ENTRY");

        var componentTypeConfigMap = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.componentTypeConfigObj));
        var componentAttributesConfigMap;

        for(var i = 0; i < fieldWrapperList.length; i++){

             componentAttributesConfigMap = {};
            //Configure Attributes
            componentAttributesConfigMap["aura:id"] = component.getGlobalId();
            componentAttributesConfigMap["label"] = fieldWrapperList[i].label;
            componentAttributesConfigMap["access"] = "Global";

            //Component Specific Attributes
            if(fieldWrapperList[i].type == "STRING"){
                componentAttributesConfigMap["class"] = "slds-input";
            }else if(fieldWrapperList[i].type == "DATETIME"){
                componentAttributesConfigMap["class"] = "slds-input";
                componentAttributesConfigMap["displayDatePicker"] = "true";
            }else if(fieldWrapperList[i].type == "REFERENCE"){
                componentAttributesConfigMap["class"] = "slds-input";
            }

            //Create Dynamic Components
            //Syntax: createComponent(String type, Object attributes, function callback) 
            $A.createComponent(
                componentTypeConfigMap[fieldWrapperList[i].type],
                componentAttributesConfigMap,
                function(dynamicCmp){
                    if(component.isValid()){
                        var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(dynamicCmp);
                        console.log(body);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }   
                }
            );
        }
        console.log("PageLayoutManager -- helper.constructDynamicComponents() -- EXIT");
    },

    componentTypeConfigObj: {
        "DATETIME" : "c:GenericInputDate",
        "REFERENCE" : "ui:inputText",
        "STRING" : "c:GenericInputTextBox"
    }
})
```

**PageLayoutManagerApexController.aspx**

```
public class PageLayoutManagerApexController {

    /* PUBLIC METHODS */
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<fieldSetWrapper> getApexFieldSetMetadata(String sObjectName, String fieldSetName, String recordId){

        Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> fieldSetMap = new Map<String, Schema.FieldSet>();

        /*
            To Do: Since the component is within <aura:iteration>, getAllFieldSets() would be called
            several items. Hence move the "fieldSetMap" to Platform Cache -- Jag
        */

        if(!String.isBlank(sObjectName)){
            fieldSetMap = getAllFieldSets(sObjectName);
        }

        //Exit quickly, if no fieldSet is found associated to sObject
        if(fieldSetMap.size() > 0){
            return getFieldMetadata(fieldSetMap, fieldSetName);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    /* PRIVATE METHODS */
    private static Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> getAllFieldSets(String sObjectName){
        //Get sObject in Schema.SObjectType format
        Schema.SObjectType sObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName);

        //Then, get sObjectResult which has all the metadata info. about sObject.
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describesObjectRes = sObjectType.getDescribe();

        //sObject Result Schema has info about fieldSets. Store it in a Map.
        Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> fieldSetMap = describesObjectRes.fieldSets.getMap();

        System.debug('FieldSet Map: ' + fieldSetMap);
        return fieldSetMap;
    }

    private static List<fieldSetWrapper> getFieldMetadata(Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> fieldSetMap, String fieldSetName){
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldSetMemberList = new List<Schema.FieldSetMember>();

        if(!String.isBlank(fieldSetName)){
            Schema.FieldSet fieldSet = fieldSetMap.get(fieldSetName);
            if(!String.isBlank(String.valueOf(fieldSet))){
                fieldSetMemberList = fieldSet.getFields();
            }
            System.debug('FieldSet Members : ' + fieldSetMemberList);

            if(fieldSetMemberList.size() > 0){
                List<fieldSetWrapper> fswList = new List<fieldSetWrapper>();
                for(Schema.FieldSetMember fsm: fieldSetMemberList){
                    fieldSetWrapper fsw = new fieldSetWrapper(fsm);
                    fswList.add(fsw);
                }
                if(fswList.size() > 0){
                    return fswList;
                }else{
                    return null;
                }
            }else{
                return null;   
            }
        }else{
            return null;  
        }
    }

    /*
        Wrapper Class
    */
    public class fieldSetWrapper{

        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean DBRequired {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public String fieldPath {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public String label {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean required {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public String type {get; set;}

        public fieldSetWrapper(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSetMember){
            this.DBRequired = fieldSetMember.getDbRequired();
            this.fieldPath = fieldSetMember.getFieldPath();
            this.label = fieldSetMember.getLabel();
            this.required = fieldSetMember.getRequired();
            this.type = String.ValueOf(fieldSetMember.getType());
        }
    }

    /* FieldSetMember Structure Reference */
    /*
        FieldSet Members: (
            Schema.FieldSetMember[
                getDbRequired = false; 
                getFieldPath = KYC_Risk_Officer__c; 
                getLabel = KYC Risk Officer; 
                getRequired = false; 
                getType = REFERENCE;
            ], 
            Schema.FieldSetMember[
                getDbRequired = false; 
                getFieldPath = Name; 
                getLabel = KYCOnboard Name; 
                getRequired = false; 
                getType = STRING;
            ]
        )
    */
}
```

**Console Log Output**

[image]

**Here is the piece of code i am trying to make it work**

```
for(var i = 0; i < fieldWrapperList.fswList.length; i++){
            $A.createComponent(
                "force:inputField",
                {
                    "aura:id" : component.getGlobalId(),
                    "label" : fieldWrapperList.fswList[i].label,
                    "value" : fieldWrapperList.sObjectInstance.KYC_Risk_Officer__c
                },
                function(dynamicCmp){
                    if(component.isValid()){
                        var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(dynamicCmp);
                        console.log(body);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }   
                }
            );
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to extend `force:inputField` component?

From what I'm seen on Aura Documentation, `force:inputField` is abstract and extensible.
If you extend this component you can use renderers to change the output DOM and assign LDS classes.

I don't know if this ok to do, I haven't found anything around avoiding extending standard components.

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The only reason i did not do that is, it did not provide much support for "Events" [force:inputField] . Currently only 1 event is supported [ie "change" event ] which might be a deal breaker if we wanted to extend this component further in future. In contrast, ui:inputField provides native support for 19 events.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to close the loop on this question.I was not able to find a better way to do this!

We took the expensive route of creating custom AURA components (Ie, UI:InputTextBox, UI:InputPhone etc..) and used them in our forms. The other reason why we did not use force:inputField is, it did provided limited OOTB support for Events.

The use-case to use fieldSets to create forms are to circumvent the usage of RecordTypes as there can be more than 200+ combinations of different Form Layouts.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into lightning:inputField? It seems to do exactly what you're looking for.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/spring-18-developers-build-secure-interactive-forms-faster.html