# Make custom, in-memory "Lightning Data Service" work

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, java, performance, lightning-events

[Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_handling_record_change.htm) is great. Multiple components are magically linked to database records. When records change in the db component show that change.

Imagine this to work **without saving change to the database**. Imagine a Lightning page with multiple components that edit a set of records. A user changes a record field in component B and the change is shown instantely in component B. **No DML** involved. Or think of editable database table displaying **Totals rows** or columns. This must be doable without any database back and forth.

My idea was that I just need to build something as the Data Service that works instantely. Components **pass it an recordId and get a reference of that record**. If the components then display or edit the record directly (by-reference and not by-value) all other components having the same reference should be "notified" of changes.

**But...it doesn't work. Calculated fields don't see the changes :-(**

---

This sequence diagram tries to explain the code listed below.

[image]

**editGrid.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="EditableGridCtrl">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Grid" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordsById" type="Map" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:handler name="requestRecord" event="c:strike_evt" action="{!c.passRecord}" />

    <c:strike_dataGrid data="{!v.data}" />
</aura:component>
```

**editGridController.js**

```
init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var records = helper.queryFromApex(cmp);
    cmp.set("v.recordsById", records);
    cmp.set("v.data", helper.toStrikeFormat(records));
},

passRecord: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var source = evt.getSource();
    var recordId = helper.getRecordId(evt);
    var record = helper.getRecord(recordId);
    source.setRecord(record);
}
```

**Strike Data Json (10 columns, 100 rows)**

```
{   
    "columns":[
        { "label":"Price", "dataType":"COMPONENT", "name":"price" },
        { "label":"Cost", "dataType":"COMPONENT", "name":"cost" },
        ...
        { "label":"Margin", "dataType":"COMPONENT", "name":"margin" }
    ],
    "rows":[
        {
            "price":{
                "type":"c:inputCell",
                "attributes":{ "recordId":"00690000002BoMV", "field":"Price" }
            },
            "cost":{
                "type":"c:inputCell",
                "attributes":{ "recordId":"00690000002BoMV", "field":"Cost" }
            },
            "margin":{ "type":"c:marginCell",
                "attributes":{ "recordId":"00690000002BoMV" }
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
```

**inputCell.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="field" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" />

    <aura:register name="requestRecord" event="c:strike_evt" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.requestRecord}" />

    <aura:method name="setRecord" action="{!c.setRecord}">
        <aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" />
    </aura:method>

    <lightning:input value="{!v.value}" />
</aura:component>
```

**inputCellController.js**

```
init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    cmp.getEvent("requestRecord")
        .setParams({ data: cmp.get("v.recordId") })
        .fire();
},

setRecord: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var params = event.getParam("arguments");
    cmp.set("v.record", params.record);
}
```

**marginCell.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" />
    <aura:attribute name="margin" type="Decimal" />

    <aura:register name="requestRecord" event="c:strike_evt" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.requestRecord}" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!record}" action="{!c.updateMargin}" />

    <aura:method name="setRecord" action="{!c.setRecord}">
        <aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" />
    </aura:method>

    <ui:outputNumber value="{!v.margin}" ... />
</aura:component>
```

**marginCellController.js**

```
requestRecord: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    // same as in inputCellController.js 
},

setRecord: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var params = event.getParam("arguments");
    cmp.set("v.record", params.record);
},

updateMargin: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var record = cmp.get("v.record");
    cmp.set("v.margin", record.Price__c - record.Cost__c);
}
```

Comment: Is the binding triggering when you set v.margin manually to a hardcoded value rather an inline calculation using fields of your data structure (I guess the code of updateMargin is triggering anyway)?
Shooting in the blind: try to set v.margin to a null value right before setting it to the real new value. 
Sidenote: type="Grid" in the editGrid is not a valid type